# Mongoose Mongo 2dsphere geoWithin

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson, mongoose-schema, 2dsphere

After reading many questions that are SO close to mine, and reading the MongoDB docs and Mongoose docs, I still cannot answer my question.

Using express 4.13.4, mongoose 4.4.10, mongodb 2.1.14 on Node 4.4.0

My Mongoose Location schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  type: {type: String},
  coordinates: []
},{_id:false});

var model = mongoose.model('LocationModel',schema);

module.exports = {
   model :  model,
   schema : schema
};
```

My `CatalogModel` schema (what I write to Mongo):

```
var locationSchema = require('./locationModel').schema;
var schema = new Schema({
    title : String, 
    format: {type: String, maxlength: 4},
    location: {type: locationSchema, required:true},
    otherStuff: String
});
schema.index({location: '2dsphere'}); // Ensures 2dsphere index for location

model = mongoose.model('CatalogModel',schema);
```

I create a concrete example and write to MongoDB (this works fine... in that I can query it in Mongo)

```
var polyEntry = new CatalogModel({
    title:"I am just a Polygon",
    otherStuff: "More stuff here",
    location:{
        type:'Polygon',
        coordinates:[[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,1]]]
    }
});
```

In Mongo, I asked the collection for the indexes:

```
db.catalogmodels.getIndexes()
```

And this is what it says (not entirely sure what this means)

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.catalogmodels"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "location_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "test.catalogmodels",
        "background" : true,
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

I can do a `db.catalogmodels.find()` and get my document back.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("12345678901234566778"), 
    "title" : "I am just a Polygon", 
    "location" : { 
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1 ] ] ] 
    },        
    "__v" : 0 
}
```

I can even do a $geoWithin call in Mongo:

```
db.catalogmodels.find(
    {
        location:{
            $geoWithin:{
                $geometry:{
                    type:"Polygon",
                    "coordinates":[[[-1,0],[-1,3],[4,3],[4,0],[-1,0]]]
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

**But here's the actual question**:

Mongoose keeps telling me ***[Error: Can't use $geoWithin]***

```
var geoJson = { 
    "type" : "Polygon", 
    "coordinates" : [[[-1,0],[-1,3],[4,3],[4,0],[-1,0]]] 
};
CatalogModel
.find()
.where('location').within(geoJson)
.exec(function(err,data){
    if ( err ) { console.log(err); }
    else {console.log("Data: " + data);}
    db.close()
});
```

I also replaced the .find().where().within() call to:

```
CatalogEntryModel.find({
    location:{
        $geoWithin:{
            $geometry:{
                type:"Polygon",
                "coordinates":[[[-1,0],[-1,3],[4,3],[4,0],[-1,0]]]
            }
        }
    }
})
.exec(function(err,data){
    if ( err ) { console.log(err); }
    else {console.log("Data: " + data);}
    db.close();
});
```

Is there a reason Mongoose does not like the $geoWithin call?  The latest API says this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up as an issue on Mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4044#

And it has been closed.